# Blackberry application (sending GPS coordinate to server...)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, blackberry, gps

I need to develope a application to send GPS coordinates (each x time) to a server (using Gprs).

Is it a simple task? Is it possible to develope that only with Javascript ? How about MDS? I installed a Visual Studio plugin to MDS.

Comment: Browser in latest blackberry has somewhat decent capabilities, supporting most of DOM1/2. What exactly are you having difficulties with?

Comment: Is it possible to do that using MDS (onky Javascript) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a very similar application but I used the Blackberry JDE plugin for Eclipse rather than the MDS for Visual Studio.  With the JDE Plugin you get a LOT more functionality and access to the API, whereas the MDS is for RAD and doesn't allow you as much control over what's happening.

I'm unsure about doing it with Javascript tho, worth checking out.